# Incorrect path to S3 flysystem adapter in Laravel 5

Tags: php, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I'm having an issue with Laravel 5's filesystem when uploading files to an S3 bucket. The line that is running to the filesystem is:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put($slug, $img);
```

It works as it should for:

```
Storage::disk('local')->put($slug, $img);
```

But when I change the disk to S3 it throws the following error:

```
Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found
```

As per the L5 docs, I have the following requirement in my composer.json

```
"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2": "~1.0"
```

which installed league's aws flysystem adapter under:

```
League\flysystem-aws-s3-v2\
```

I have tried updating the path in the fileSystemManager.php in the filesystem vendor folder to the aws flysystem installation path but it still doesn't work. I can't seem to find anyone else who has experienced this behaviour.

A fresh pair of eyes or a knowledgeable head who might know more about Laravel than I would be great. I really can't seem to the issue.

**UPDATE**

I did a fresh install of the aws flysystem and not I get the following:

```
ErrorException in Util.php line 250:
fstat() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok so I fixed the initial issue by removing `aws/aws-sdk-php : "^2.8.*` that I had in my `composer.json` and ran a fresh 'composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ~1.0'. This fixed the initial error in finding the S3 flysystem.

The second error `fstat() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given` related to my attempt to pass an image object to the put method:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put($slug, $img);
```

when it expects a string. This was fixed by stringifying the $img object

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put($slug, $img->__toString());
```

Hope this helps somebody else who might encounter this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Any idea why we need to stringify the object? This feels a bit strange. Thanks!